# MYSQL IN Statement syntax not working

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to obtain records from a MYSQL database based on identifiers contained in an array. To get the identifiers my code is as follows:

```
$query="SELECT agent_id FROM agent_coverage WHERE primary_area LIKE '$search_term%'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Could not obtain primary area coverage2");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $agent_primary[]=$r['agent_id'];
}
```

This seems to work fine when using `print_r` to access the array details.

My next statement which is the one that fails is as follows:

```
if(!empty($agent_primary))
{
    $ids=join(",", $agent_primary);
    $query5="SELECT * FROM detail_db WHERE user_id IN($ids)";
    $result5=mysqli_query($dbc, $query5) or die("Could not do SELECT");

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
    {
    //do stuff with results here.
    }
}
```

This just fires the `die()` statement. I have tried using `implode` instead of `join` with no success.

edit:
`die($dbc->error)` after the failing query reveals the error to be: `unknown column '' in where clause`

Comment: use IN ('1', '2', ...)

Comment: what does `var_dump($query5);` output?

Comment: Where is `$dbc` defined?

Comment: '$dbc' is defined at the beginning of the script. This is the db connection details.

Comment: And how? Please show all relevant code.

Comment: Use `die("Could not do SELECT: ".$dbc->error)` to get the reason for the failure.

Comment: `$dbc ` works throughout the code as can be seen by the first database query returning the array

Comment: mysqli_error comes up unknown row and takes the first result from the array

Comment: I've never heard of "unknown row" error. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Sorry - unknown column '' in where clause

Comment: user_id is not a valid column name or ?

Comment: user_id is valid - the unknown column error refers to the first user_id returned by the `$agent_primary` array. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: That willl happen if one of the `agent_id` values is `\`\``

Comment: use $ids="'".join("','",$agent_primary)."'";

Comment: @Akam If you put quotes around it, then it's not a comma-separated list any more.

Comment: What does `var_dump($agent_primary)` show?

Comment: not its comma separated please just try it!

Comment: `var_dump($agent_primary)` lists out the returned array

Comment: I know that's what it does, that's why I asked you to post it.

Comment: `array(17) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "33ln1357136085"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "6sdn1357137233"
  [2]=>

}
Could not do array joinUnknown column '33ln1357136085' in 'where clause'` This has been shortened + I have grouped the results since the original question was posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$agent_primary[]="'".$dbc->real_escape_string($r['agent_id'])."'";
```

Comment: `$agent_primary[]="'".$r['agent_id']."'";` seems to work nicely - this is thanks to your above suggestion :)

Comment: @Sideshow: I have suggested to do that from begging! but you didn't applied!

Comment: @Akam Sorry, it was really hard to read in the comment. And you didn't use `real_escape_string()`, which is needed to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @Akam I couldn't tell what you were using as the argument to `join()`, the single and double quotes look alike in the tiny comment font.

Comment: @Akam - There were quite a few suggestions to trial and they came thick and fast - got a bit confusing at some point :) Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT agent_id FROM agent_coverage WHERE primary_area LIKE '$search_term%'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Could not obtain primary area coverage2");

$agent_primary=array();    

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  array_push($agent_primary,$r['agent_id']);
}
```

then

```
if(!empty($agent_primary))
{
$ids=$agent_primary;
$query5="SELECT * FROM detail_db WHERE user_id IN($ids)";
$result5=mysqli_query($dbc, $query5) or die("Could not do SELECT");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
{
//do stuff with results here.
}
}
```

use this. I think it will help you.

Comment: How can that work? `$ids` is an array, so it will just interpolate the word `Array`.

Comment: plz see full code. in my code here is also array_push($agent_primary,$r['agent_id']); this code

Comment: That just adds an element to the array, just like the original `$agent_primary[] = $r['agent_id'];`. It's still an array. IN requires a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Use implode to create a string and append brackets around it.

Get values of ids in a array and then implode it. 
Just see below example - This works.

```
 $arr = array(1,297,298);
    $new = '(';
    $new .= implode(',',$arr);
    $new .= ')';
    $query = "Select * from wp_posts where ID IN $new";
```

Comment: Yes - it gets an array of all the agent ids that match a certain criteria

Answer (score 0):

edit: Both queries can be combined with a JOIN stament

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        dd.user_id,
        dd.foo
    FROM
        tmp_agent_coverage as ac
    LEFT JOIN
        tmp_detail_db as dd
    ON
        ac.agent_id=dd.user_id
    WHERE
        ac.primary_area LIKE '$search_term%'
";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or mysqliError($dbc, "Could not obtain primary area coverage2");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $r['user_id'], ' ', $r['foo'], "\n";
}
```

---

edit2: self-contained example

```
<?php
$dbc = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
if ($dbc->connect_error) {
    var_dump($mysqli->connect_errno, $mysqli->connect_error);
    die;
}
setup($dbc);
$search_term = 'xy';

$query = "
    SELECT
        dd.user_id,
        dd.foo
    FROM
        tmp_agent_coverage as ac
    LEFT JOIN
        tmp_detail_db as dd
    ON
        ac.agent_id=dd.user_id
    WHERE
        ac.primary_area LIKE '$search_term%'
";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or mysqliError($dbc, "Could not obtain primary area coverage2");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $r['user_id'], ' ', $r['foo'], "\n";
}

define('DEVELOPMENT_DEBUG_MESSAGES', 1);
function mysqliError($dbc, $description) {
    if ( !defined('DEVELOPMENT_DEBUG_MESSAGES') || !DEVELOPMENT_DEBUG_MESSAGES ) {
        echo '<div class="error">', htmlspecialchars($description), '</div>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<fieldset class="error"><legend>', htmlspecialchars($description), '</legend>',
            htmlspecialchars($dbc->error), '</div>';
    }
}

function setup($dbc) {
    $q = array(
        'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_agent_coverage (
            agent_id int auto_increment,
            primary_area varchar(32),
            primary key(agent_id),
            key(primary_area)
        )',
        "INSERT INTO tmp_agent_coverage (primary_area) VALUES ('xy1'),('dfg'),('xy2'),('abc'),('xy3')",
        'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_detail_db (
            user_id int auto_increment,
            foo varchar(32),
            primary key(user_id)
        )',
        "INSERT INTO tmp_detail_db (foo) VALUES ('fooxy1'),('foodfg'),('fooxy2'),('fooabc'),('fooxy3')"
    );
    foreach($q as $query) {
        $dbc->query($query) or die(__LINE__ .' '.$query. ' '. $dbc->error);
    }
}
```

prints

```
1 fooxy1
3 fooxy2
5 fooxy3
```

---

original answer:
`mysqli::query` returning false means that an error occured while executing the query. That could be e.g. a syntax error or privileges or ... or ...
The `error` and `errno` properties of your $dbc object should hold more detailed information about the error. But you shouldn't show the complete error message to just any arbitrary user.
So, for debugging purposes define a function like

```
define('DEVELOPMENT_DEBUG_MESSAGES', 1);
function mysqliError($dbc, $description) {
    if ( !defined('DEVELOPMENT_DEBUG_MESSAGES') || !DEVELOPMENT_DEBUG_MESSAGES ) {
        echo '<div class="error">', htmlspecialchars($description), '</div>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<fieldset class="error"><legend>', htmlspecialchars($description), '</legend>',
            htmlspecialchars($dbc->error), '</div>';
    }
}
```

and then use this function in your code like

```
<?php
define('DEVELOPMENT_DEBUG_MESSAGES', 1);
[...]
$query="SELECT agent_id FROM agent_coverage WHERE primary_area LIKE '$search_term%'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or mysqliError($dbc, "Could not obtain primary area coverage2");
```

remove the `define(...)` line when you're done debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
if(!empty($agent_primary))
{
    $ids=implode($agent_primary,",");
    $query5="SELECT * FROM detail_db WHERE user_id IN ($ids)";
    $result5=mysqli_query($dbc, $query5) or die("Could not do SELECT");

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
    {
    //do stuff with results here.
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $ids=join("','", $agent_primary);
 $query5="SELECT * FROM detail_db WHERE user_id IN('$ids')";
```

i tried it in my localhost and it works perfect!